# Tag with multiple definitions

Tags: support, tag-wiki

[Here's a tag (map)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/map/info) that has one definition (as in a dictionary/associate array).

Now there's an edit pending that adds a second definition -- `map` as in map/reduce, functional programming etc.

IMHO these are both valid definitions of `map` -- but they shouldn't be in the same tag, because somebody searching for `map/reduce` shouldn't be overwhelmed with results for dictionaries.

**What should we do about this?**